# EF Core Query Filter Extension Method

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, multi-tenant

My DbContext code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        => userService = DbContextExtension.ServiceCollection.CheckService<IUserService>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        SetTenantQueryFilter<ClassRoom>(builder);
        SetTenantQueryFilter<Course>(builder);
        SetTenantQueryFilter<Demo>(builder);
        SetTenantQueryFilter<Student>(builder);
        SetTenantQueryFilter<Teacher>(builder);
    }

    private void SetTenantQueryFilter<TEntity>(ModelBuilder builder) where TEntity : class, IUserIsolation
        => builder.Entity<TEntity>().HasQueryFilter(s => s.TenantId == userService.CurrentUserId);
}
```

Generated SQL Query:

```
Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__ef_filter__CurrentUserId_0='b00ffd0d-1fd1-ed11-bef1-f8b54d53dd5f' (Size = 255), @__p_0='0', @__p_1='10'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      SELECT [s].[ID], [s].[AcademicYear], [s].[Address], [s].[Age], [s].[AuditId], [s].[ClassRoomId], [s].[CourseId], [s].[Email], [s].[Name], [s].[PhoneNumbers], [s].[SoftDeleteId], [s].[StudentType], [s].[SynchronizeId], [s].[TeacherId], [s].[TenantId], [s].[Url]
      FROM [Student] AS [s]
      WHERE [s].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__CurrentUserId_0
      ORDER BY [s].[Name]
      OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
```

This is working fine.

But I tried to make extension method. My code is

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.SetTenantQueryFilter<ClassRoom>();
        builder.SetTenantQueryFilter<Course>();
        builder.SetTenantQueryFilter<Demo>();
        builder.SetTenantQueryFilter<Student>();
        builder.SetTenantQueryFilter<Teacher>();
    }
}

public static class DbExtension
{
    private static readonly IUserService UserService = DbContextExtension.ServiceCollection.CheckService<IUserService>();

    public static void SetTenantQueryFilter<TEntity>(this ModelBuilder builder) where TEntity : class, IUserIsolation
        => builder.Entity<TEntity>().HasQueryFilter(s => s.TenantId == UserService.CurrentUserId);
}
```

Generated SQL Query:

```
Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='0', @__p_1='10'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      SELECT [s].[ID], [s].[AcademicYear], [s].[Address], [s].[Age], [s].[AuditId], [s].[ClassRoomId], [s].[CourseId], [s].[Email], [s].[Name], [s].[PhoneNumbers], [s].[SoftDeleteId], [s].[StudentType], [s].[SynchronizeId], [s].[TeacherId], [s].[TenantId], [s].[Url]
      FROM [Student] AS [s]
      WHERE [s].[TenantId] = N'b00ffd0d-1fd1-ed11-bef1-f8b54d53dd5f'
      ORDER BY [s].[Name]
      OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
```

It was failed while switching tenant. (means one time only setting the Query filter)

Even I tried pass UserService in DI from OnModelCreating not working.

`builder.SetTenantQueryFilter<ClassRoom>(userService);`

Comment: In query filter you can use ONLY property of DbContext.

Comment: Tip from official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters): *"Note the use of a `DbContext` instance level field: `_tenantId` used to set the current tenant. Model-level filters will use the value from the correct context instance (that is, the instance that is executing the query)."* Wish they specify that requirement explicitly as part of the feature instead of example tip ("and btw, note ..."), but it is what it is.

Comment: I achieve the multi-tenant behavior. The problem is I want it like extension method. To reduce the configuration easy.

Comment: @KannanChithamabaranathan You are missing the point, which is `DbContext` **instance level field**. It could be field, property or method, but **must** be **instance member of the db context**, otherwise it will evaluate just once, as you already saw.